# Why is my code only accesing the Second while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a little bit of code "Wormy.py", and i tried to add a teleport portal. For now it's working but only on 1 block, it only acces the second whili loop for some reason, any ideas why and how to fix it?

I tried adding else: return but that isn't working and the break isn't working either

```
# Wormy (a Nibbles clone)
# By Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com
# http://inventwithpython.com/pygame
# Released under a "Simplified BSD" license

import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 15
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
CELLSIZE = 20
assert WINDOWWIDTH % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of cell size."
assert WINDOWHEIGHT % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of cell size."
CELLWIDTH = int(WINDOWWIDTH / CELLSIZE)
CELLHEIGHT = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / CELLSIZE)

#             R    G    B
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
RED       = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 155,   0)
DARKGRAY  = ( 40,  40,  40)
BGCOLOR = BLACK

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

HEAD = 0 # syntactic sugar: index of the worm's head

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Wormy')

    showStartScreen()
    while True:
        runGame()
        showGameOverScreen()


def runGame():
    worm1 = False
    # Set a random start point.
    startx = random.randint(5, CELLWIDTH - 6)
    starty = random.randint(5, CELLHEIGHT - 6)
    wormCoords = [{'x': startx,     'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 1, 'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 2, 'y': starty}]
    direction1 = RIGHT

    startx_wormhole1 = 2
    starty_wormhole1 = 2
    startx_wormhole2 = 29
    starty_wormhole2 = 2
    wallCoords1 = [{'x': startx_wormhole1,  'y': starty_wormhole1}]
    wallCoords2 = [{'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}]


    # Start the apple in a random place.
    apple = getRandomLocation()

    while True:  # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT) and direction1 != RIGHT:  # snake 1
                    direction1 = LEFT
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT) and direction1 != LEFT:
                    direction1 = RIGHT
                elif (event.key == K_UP) and direction1 != DOWN:
                    direction1 = UP
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN) and direction1 != UP:
                    direction1 = DOWN

        # check if the worm1 has hit itself or the edge
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == CELLWIDTH or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == -1 or \
                wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == CELLHEIGHT:
            if direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': CELLHEIGHT - 1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': 0}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': CELLWIDTH - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            elif direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': 0, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            worm1 = True




        if not worm1:
            if direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] - 1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] + 1}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            elif direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] + 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
        else:
            worm1 = False

        print(newHead)

        if newHead in wallCoords2:
            if direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
            elif direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
            else:
                if newHead in wallCoords1:
                    if direction1 == RIGHT:
                        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
                    elif direction1 == LEFT:
                        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
                    elif direction1 == UP:
                        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
                    elif direction1 == DOWN:
                        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}



        # check if worm has eaten an apply
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
            # don't remove worm's tail segment
            apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere
        else:
            del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment



        wormCoords.insert(0, newHead)
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawGrid()
        drawWorm(wormCoords)
        drawWall(wallCoords1)
        drawWall(wallCoords2)
        drawApple(apple)
        drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)




def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)


def checkForKeyPress():
    if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
        terminate()

    keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
    if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
        return None
    if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
        terminate()
    return keyUpEvents[0].key


def showStartScreen():
    titleFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    titleSurf1 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, WHITE, DARKGREEN)
    titleSurf2 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, GREEN)

    degrees1 = 0
    degrees2 = 0
    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf1, degrees1)
        rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
        rotatedRect1.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf1, rotatedRect1)

        rotatedSurf2 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf2, degrees2)
        rotatedRect2 = rotatedSurf2.get_rect()
        rotatedRect2.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf2, rotatedRect2)

        drawPressKeyMsg()

        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
        degrees1 += 3 # rotate by 3 degrees each frame
        degrees2 += 7 # rotate by 7 degrees each frame


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def getRandomLocation():
    return {'x': random.randint(0, CELLWIDTH - 1), 'y': random.randint(0, CELLHEIGHT - 1)}


def showGameOverScreen():
    gameOverFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 150)
    gameSurf = gameOverFont.render('Game', True, WHITE)
    overSurf = gameOverFont.render('Over', True, WHITE)
    gameRect = gameSurf.get_rect()
    overRect = overSurf.get_rect()
    gameRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, 10)
    overRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, gameRect.height + 10 + 25)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(gameSurf, gameRect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(overSurf, overRect)
    drawPressKeyMsg()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500)
    checkForKeyPress() # clear out any key presses in the event queue

    while True:
        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return

def drawScore(score):
    scoreSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score: %s' % (score), True, WHITE)
    scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
    scoreRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 120, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)


def drawWorm(wormCoords):
    for coord in wormCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
        wormSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGREEN, wormSegmentRect)
        wormInnerSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x + 4, y + 4, CELLSIZE - 8, CELLSIZE - 8)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, wormInnerSegmentRect)

def drawWall(wallCoords):
    for coord in wallCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
        wallSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, wallSegmentRect)

def drawApple(coord):
    x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
    y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
    appleRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, appleRect)


def drawGrid():
    for x in range(0, WINDOWWIDTH, CELLSIZE): # draw vertical lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x, 0), (x, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    for y in range(0, WINDOWHEIGHT, CELLSIZE): # draw horizontal lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0, y), (WINDOWWIDTH, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: hello, can you fix the indent plz, currently you cant access the second while loop wihout accessing the first one

Comment: It can be that the first block is working but the result is getting overwritten by the second block? Did you confirm that?

Comment: There is obviously some indentation problem here, in python indentation is really important. But beside that could you give us the wallCoords1 ? You will not enter this loop if it is empty.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's impossible to answer your question without a proper minimal, complete and verifiable example. Please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of points I would make:
 In the outer loop, you are using the variable newHead as an instance of the data structure wallCoords and then assigning a new value to wallCoords within the loop. It would be better practice to assign the new coordinates to another variable.

In the inner loop, you are doing exactly the same reassignment to the newHead variable. But your other problem in the inner loop is that you are using newHead again as an instance of the data structure wallCoords.

With the fact that you are continually assigning a value to newHead may not solve the problem your initial problem, it will certainly solve the problem around the desired output from the code.

Comment: What do i have to do to fixs this?

Comment: I would do something like this. 
 
while newHead2 in wallCoords2:
    if direction1 == RIGHT:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
    ...

There are still a  lot of questions 
I would guess that wallCoords2 is a list or dictionary but in the loop, you are not using the value that comes out of the data structure wallCoords2. I would also ask where the value direction1 is defined, does that come from wallCoords2? 
But are the two loops nested or not?

Answer (score -2):

2nd While loop is inside the first one, that's the main problem. Try to re-indent and then retest your code.

```
while newHead in wallCoords1:
    if direction1 == RIGHT:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
    elif direction1 == LEFT:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
    elif direction1 == UP:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}
    elif direction1 == DOWN:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole2, 'y': starty_wormhole2}



while newHead in wallCoords2:
    if direction1 == RIGHT:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
    elif direction1 == LEFT:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
    elif direction1 == UP:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
    elif direction1 == DOWN:
        newHead = {'x': startx_wormhole1, 'y': starty_wormhole1}
```

more about indenting in Python http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3

Comment: That is a typo in stackoverflow in my code it is like you daid but still accesing the 2nde loop

Comment: wallCoords1 = [{`x': 2 'y': 2}]

Comment: I tried it but it's still accesing the second loop, doesn't make sense to me. why is it skipping the first while loop?

Comment: @Kaochi as some of us already mentionned, it's impossible to answer your question without knowing the effective values of your variables. Please edit your question to provide a minimal complete and verifiable example (cf  https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: I added the full code, i run the code with MU editor, i changed the while to if but still not working